# If an Euler-Lagrange equation is satisfied by all diffeomorphisms, is it Null-Lagrangian?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $B^n$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let

$L:\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \times \mathbb{R}^n \times B^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth Lagrangian; Define $E:C^{\infty}(B^n,B^n) \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$ E(u)=\int_{B^n} L\big(Du(x),u(x),x\big)dx.$$

Now, suppose that for every two balls $B_1,B_2 \subseteq B^n$ and for every diffeomorphism $f:B_1 \to B_2$, $f$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrangian equation of $E$.

Is it true that every smooth map $h:B^n \to B^n$ satisfies it?

i.e, is $L$ a null-Lagrangian?

My intuition is that since the E-L equation for a map $f$ is "smooth" in $f$, and we know it holds for all "small diffeomorphisms", we can perhaps approximate an arbitrary map (locally) via diffeomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\R{\mathbb R}$Let $$J=J^2(B^n,B^n) = B^n \times B^n \times L(\R^n,\R^n) \times L(\mathrm{Sym}^2 \R^n,\R^n)$$ denote the space of $2$-jets from $B^n$ to itself. Given a $C^2$ map $u : B^n \to B^n$, we can define its prolongation $j^2u : B^n \to J$ by $$j^2u(x) = (x, u(x), Du(x), D^2u(x)).$$
I'm going to refer to the corresponding coordinates on the jet space by $(x,y,p,\xi).$ The Euler-Lagrange equation for $L$ can be written as $F \circ j^2 u = 0$ where $F : J \to \R^n$ is defined by $$ F^i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial y^i} - \left(\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial p^i_j \partial x^j} + \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial p^i_j \partial y^k}p^k_j + \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial p^i_j \partial p^k_l} \xi^k_{lj}\right).$$

Note that smoothness of $L$ implies continuity of $F$.

The point of all this is that whenever $u$ is a solution, we immediately know that $F$ is zero on the image of $j^2 u$. Now, given an arbitrary jet $q=(x,y,p,\xi) \in J$ such that $p$ is invertible, we can find$^1$ a diffeomorphism $u$ such that $j^2u(x) = q$; so the assumption that $u$ is a solution tells us that $F(q) = 0$. Since the set of invertible matrices is dense in $L(\R^n,\R^n)$, the set of such good jets $q$ is dense in $J$; and thus $F$ vanishes everywhere by continuity.

$^1$This point is slightly technical - see e.g. [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088706/k-jet-transitivity-of-diffeomorphism-group), though I'm sure it's much easier in this case since $k=2$ and we're only on the ball.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected such "genericity" should hold. If I am interpreting correctly what you are saying, then it is enough to require that all *global* diffeomorphisms are critical for the corollary to hold, right?. (There is no need to require this for all "smaller diffeomorphisms" defined over smaller subsets). I am actually interested in a wider manifold context, so your answer probably helps me very much! (I still need to understand some details regarding your jet notations etc, since I am not used to it, but I will try first on my own:). Thanks again.

Comment: @AsafShachar: ah, yes, you're right about me using only global diffeomorphisms. I missed the part of your question where you allowed the diffeomorphisms to be local. With that stronger assumption it's very easy to construct the diffeomorphism we need - just restrict the polynomial $u(z) = y + p \cdot z + \frac12 z^T \xi z$ to a small enough ball around $x$.

Comment: ^that should be $u(x+z)$.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure then: I have a functional $E$ over mappings between two $d$-dimensional manifolds, with the property that every local diffeomorphism is a critical point of $E$. Then every (smooth) map should be critical as well? (I am trying to make sure your argument adapts to that setting; In particular I don't want to assume the two manifolds are diffeomorphic, so I can't work with global diff').

Comment: @Asaf: So long as the functional is obtained by integrating some $C^{2k}$ Lagrangian $L : J^k(M,N) \to \mathbb R$, yes: the E-L equation will be of the form $F_L \circ j^{2k} u = 0$, and the same argument will work to show that jets of local diffeomorphisms are dense in $J^{2k}$: if $p$ is invertible, just pass to coordinates and (restricting to a small enough ball that $p$ dominates) you can use the polynomial with coefficients $y,p,\xi,\ldots$.